# Get an acute/backtick/left quote aka this thing ` in Latex

Tags: punctuation

I am creating a document where I need to have the following output from latex:

**display "`example'"**

This is for an exercise for my programming class. It naturally needs to read exactly like that - double inverted commas, then the elusive backtick I so desire, then some text of little import, then the single inverted comma, followed by the double again. I am struggling just to get the backtick as Latex has its own way of interpreting this. I have tried to escape it with backslash but that then gives me a diacritic. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update: I have learned that another name for the character I seek is a grave accent.

Regards,
Bruce

Comment: ``\verb|lisp quotes symbols like `this|`` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for your answer. The verb environment sort of works but it doesn't look great as you can't distinguish the backtick from a normal single inverted comma. The backtick is shorter and doesnt have the bulge at the end. Unfortunately I don't think I can share a picture to show you.

Comment: (left quote is grave, not acute) is the intent to display “‘example’” (here I actually used the unicode inverted commas of appropriate type)?

Comment: Yes I came to same conclusion, posted an answer with some alternatives

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\verb|"`example'"|

\textquotedbl\textasciigrave example\textquotesingle\textquotedbl

\texttt{\textquotedbl\textasciigrave example\textquotesingle\textquotedbl}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could achieve this in quite a simple way. I just had to first learn that it is called a grave accent, which you can apply as a diacritic with `` \`{} ``. If you don't put anything inside the {} you effectively get a lone grave accent, which is what I wanted. So, solution was exactly as follows:

``\`{}example'''

giving

**"`example'"**

Comment: sort of. but it's a bit unbalanced with the curly apostrophe

Comment: Yes I think I am actually going to go with your suggestion. Thanks a ton

Comment: I fixed up the quoting of the quote and added an image of the output which you undid? (it's your post you are quite free to do that but just checking that's what you intended?)